# Extracting lines based on conditions

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sed, awk

Each line in a comma-separated file has 5 fields.

```
a,b,c,d,e
f,g,c,i,
j,k,c,m,n
o,p,c,r,s
t,u,c,w,
x,y,z,aa,bb
```

How can I extract the lines which have c in the 3rd field and their 5th field is NOT empty? The result would be:

```
a,b,c,d,e
j,k,c,m,n
o,p,c,r,s
```

Comment: We always like to see, what you tried in order to help you find the solution on your own. Otherwise it looks like you want to us to solve your homework for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Possible solution with `awk`:

```
awk -F',' '$3 == "c" && $5' file
```

Depending on actual data this may not work as desired as mentioned in comments (thanks Janis for pointing this: it will miss `f,g,c,i,0` e.g 5th field is 0) so you can do following:

```
awk -F',' '$3 == "c" && $5 != ""' file
```

And as this is the accepted answer I am adding not so obvious forcing 5th field to string (as in cuonglm(+1) solution):

```
awk -F',' '$3 == "c" && $5""' file
```

Comment: Note that, depending on the actual data, this may not work as desired. It would not match `f,g,c,i,0`, i.e. with a `0` in the last column. The fix is of course easy: `awk -F',' '$3 == "c" && $5 != ""`.

Comment: @Janis: `$5""` is enough. See [my answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/206600/38906)

Comment: @cuonglm; Yes, forcing the field to string is also possible. But, IMO, it's still less clear than spending two more characters to create the explicit and (also to `awk` beginners!) more obvious condition `$5!=""`.

Answer (score 3):

```
sed -n '/,$/!s/^\([^,]*,\)\{2\}c/&/p'
```

...will work for a POSIX `sed`. If you can use a `sed` which implements AT&T *Augmented* regular expressions - such as the one freely available in the [astopen](http://www2.research.att.com/~astopen/download/) package - you could do it like:

```
sed -nX '/^(([^,]*,){2}c.*)&(.*,)!$/p'
```

Of course, if the latter case is true, you probably have a similar `grep` *(as can be compiled as a `ksh93` builtin, incidentally)* and so you should probably do instead:

```
grep -xX '(([^,]*,){2}c.*)&(.*,)!'
```

Comment: Your sed logic is insufficient: you're just checking that the line does not end with a comma, not whether the 5th field is not empty. You'll miss a line like `a,b,c,d,e,`

Comment: @glennjackman - Not at all. The description of the file is: *Each line in a comma-separated file has 5 fields.* Admittedly if that were not the case an additional test like `'s/,//5;t'` might be called for.

Answer (score 2):

With `awk`:

```
awk -F, '$3 == "c" && $5""' file
```

In `awk`, `0` and `""` are two false values in boolean context. So if you do something like `$3 == "c" && $5`, you will miss lines which the fifth field is `0`. `$5""` force `awk` coerce fifth field to string, string `"0"` will be evaluated to true.

Answer (score 0):

With perl you could do something like:

```
perl -F, -nlae 'print if $F[2] eq "c" and $F[4] ne ""'
```

The `-a` option splits the lines by the delimiter specified by the `-F` option and you can afterwards simply check the fields in the `@F` array.

Answer (score 0):

Using `python`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python2
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        fields = line.rstrip().split(',')
        if fields[2] == 'c' and fields[4]:
            print line.rstrip()
```

Here we have taken the fields of each line splitted on comma (`,`) into a list (`fields`) and then we have checked the conditions on the required fields.

Comment: I would assign the `rstrip()` to a new variable  and the output from split as well and re-use that for as more readable and faster solution

Comment: @Anthon yeah, you are right..answer edited..